# Objective-c: What does return type __strong const char * mean?

Tags: objective-c

When reading the headers of Foundation I found this:

```
- (__strong const char *)UTF8String NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER;   
// Convenience to return null-terminated UTF8 representation
```

This is from `NSString.h` in the iOS 7.1 SDK, what does `__strong const char *` mean here?

I'm most confused about the `"__strong"` here.

Comment: Interesting question. Perhaps you should re-formulate it slightly to emphasize that it is about the __strong attribute used with a non-Object type (and not about const char * :-). I noted that if you define your own method `-(__strong const char *)foo  NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER;` then the compiler warns that *"'__strong' only applies to Objective-C object or block pointer types; type here is 'const char *'"*.

Comment: @MartinR The fact that the warning is not issued for the `UTF8String` declaration is probably only due to the fact that clang (and other compilers) suppress warnings in system headers.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe: You are right. Including a local copy of NSString.h gives the same warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Foundation is shared between iOS and Mac OS. On Mac OS, for a while there existed a garbage collection memory management system. It's now deprecated and not longer supported on Mac OS. It was never used on iOS.

GC used `__strong` as a modifier on plain pointer type declarations to make the pointed to memory collectible. *This usage* of `__strong` has no meaning in ARC or manual retain/release code. The fact that there's no warning for the declaration is probably only because clang issues no warnings in system headers.

Comment: `__strong` also has a meaning in ARC: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Comment: Well, of course it has a meaning in ARC. But the usage under ARC is constrained to "retainable object types". In this case a plain pointer is decorated with `__strong` and **this** has no meaning in ARC.

Answer (score 0):

`NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER` is a Clang annotation that indicates the method returns a pointer to one of its inner data structures (i.e., an instance variable), *and* that inner variable is not reference-counted, so whenever that method is called, ARC should increment the retain count for the *receiver* (because that object should not be released as long as the pointer to its inner data structures is in use).

In this case, `__strong` essentially acts in conjunction with `NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER` to indicate the lifetime of an object that returned a pointer to its inner data structures.

Comment: "__strong essentially acts in conjunction with NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER". I can't find documentation on this.

Answer (score -1):

`__strong` means that the object (of class NSString in this case), that holds the pointer, retains its ownership till the end of the life of the object and the pointed memory will be garbage-collected. Hence `INNER`.

`const char *` means that the `char` array this pointer points to is constant, i.e. cannot be changed for example by changing some characters in it (you will get a compiler error).

If you try to compile this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    NSString *s = @"string";
    const char *str = [s UTF8String];
    printf("%s\n", str);
    str[0] = 'S';
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

you'll get `read-only variable is not assignable` error.

Comment: `__strong` is used on a plain pointer here, not an object type. That's not documented to mean something in the ARC specification.